# Why Won't My Div Move?

Tags: javascript, html, move

I am trying to get this fat `div` on some moving, but it won't! Help!

```js
<script>

do {
 setTimeout(fly(), 10)
  function fly() {
   var i = 0;
      var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("dick").style.left);
   var top = parseInt(document.getElementById("dick").style.top);
   left++;
   top++;
   document.getElementById("dick").style.left = left + "px";
   document.getElementById("dick").style.top = top + "px"; 
 } 
}

while (i = 0);
</script>
```

```html
<div id="dick" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000000;"></div>
```

Comment: "i" is not in the scope of the do...while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **setInterval** instead of **setTimeout**. Also you should give the **setInterval** your function instead of giving it the result of it being called.

```
    setInterval(fly, 10);
    function fly() {
      console.log("flying")
        var i = 0;
        var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("dick").style.left);
        var top = parseInt(document.getElementById("dick").style.top);
        left++;
        top++;
        document.getElementById("dick").style.left = left + "px";
        document.getElementById("dick").style.top = top + "px"; 
}
```

check this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/L3cid26ybpFYITfjUbmP?p=preview

Comment: Whoa, how does the dick keep moving, I can't see any `while`etc!

Comment: the while there doesn't do anything, it should be removed.

Comment: Ooh okay I see, the `setInterval` keeps doing stuff every, in this case, 10ms!

Answer (score 1):

Because the code is full of logical mistakes.

```js
setInterval(fly, 100);

function fly() {
    var i = 0,
        el = document.getElementById("dick"),
        left = parseInt(el.style.left),
        top = parseInt(el.style.top);

 el.style.left = ++left + "px";
 el.style.top = ++top + "px"; 
}
```

```html
<div id="dick" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#000000;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way it is now, you should see this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

First, move your script afterwards the `<body>` tag;

Then, try coding something like this, instead:

```
function fly() {
        var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("dick").style.left);
        var top = parseInt(document.getElementById("dick").style.top);
        left++;
        top++;
        document.getElementById("dick").style.left = left + "px";
        document.getElementById("dick").style.top = top + "px";
        //nsole.log(left+" and "+top);
    }

    var T_TIME = 200; // ms
    var intHandler = window.setInterval("fly()", T_TIME);
```

You better use setInverval() instead of a setTimeout with a loop.